# What are the Implications of WCF TimeoutException vs CommunicationException on method execution?

Tags: wcf, exception

I'm making a call to a WCF service that will initiate a batch of credit card charges. If an exception occurs, I want to know whether it occurred prior to the method executing and cards actually being charged. For example, with a TimeoutException, there's no way to know whether the WCF method executed so I need to make sure those charges aren't retried until the situation is investigated. But if the network was just down, or the server cert expired, or anything else happened prior to the method actually executing, I can un-lock my records to be retried later without human intervention.

```
try
{
    var response = wcfClient.ProcessBatch(paymentBatch);
    wcfClient.Close();

    //...
}
catch(CommunicationException)
{
    //Safe to assume ProcessBatch did not execute?

    wcfClient.Abort();
}
catch(TimeoutException)
{
    //Indeterminate state. Have to assume operation may have succeeded server-side

    wcfClient.Abort();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //Assuming operation may have succeeded server-side
}
```

This is using a `wsHttpBinding`. Does a `CommunicationException` guarantee the method did not execute or could it also be thrown during the response?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the CommunicationException documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.communicationexception?view=netframework-4.8), a CommunicationException Exceptioon is a superclass of errors that fall into two subcategories, both related to to errors in the SOAP datagram.

Conversely, a [TimeoutException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeoutexception?view=netframework-4.8) is pretty straightforward: "The exception that is thrown when the time allotted for a process or operation has expired." The allotted time is probably set by the owner of the service, and you may or may not have a mechanism by which to override it.

For future reference, two quick Bing searches returned both of the articles cited herein.

Comment: "Two subcategories" - do you mean `FaultException` and `FaultException<TDetail>`? Those are two of the many derived types; I don't know about categories. What's the relevancy of those to this question? I'm not finding an answer to the question here. For fair comparison, I've found the docs also appear in simple google and duckduckgo searches...